# Regresar a la ventana principal

Tags: python

Necesito su ayuda, estoy realizando un script para seleccionar varias semanas del año y poder realizar algunas validaciones. Hasta el momento todo va bien, sin embargo, quiero que cuando se presione el botón *Cancelar* en el ccbox de easygui se devuelva a la ventana principal para escoger las semanas correspondiente.

Esto es lo que llevo del código

```
lista = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21',
         '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40',
         '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52']
opcs = eg.multchoicebox(msg='Seleccione las semanas a reportar',
                        title='Semanas',
                        choices=lista, preselect=None)
if opcs != None:
    output = eg.ccbox('Semanas seleccionadas: '+str(opcs), title = 'Las semanas seleccionadas', choices = ('Continuar', 'Cancelar'))
```

Comment: Probaste con usar un bucle while?